# want to change url last parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to change the last parameter of the URL, `order=desc`, to `order=asc` without refreshing the browser. The code should be work at run time.

```
http://localhost/ci/city.php?cities=mombai&cat_type=1&order=desc
```

I have to make one `img` work for `asc` and second for `desc`

```html
Sort By:
<img src="/ci/_images/template/arrow_top.png"  width="12px" /> |
<img src="/ci/_images/template/arrow_bottom.png"  width="12px" /> |
```

Comment: There is more to this than just changing the URL parameter - you need to make an AJAX request based on the new sort order and update the page.

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan apperently you have no idea how this site work so please visit the help section to get an overview

Comment: if you dont want to refresh or redirect then why do you want to change the url parameter?

Comment: (a) You want to redirect page without redirecting it - that is nonsense (b) you want to change contents of current page with javascript to make it look like it redirected to another page, without actually redirecting it - that is a task for javascript, DOM and maybe AJAX and is equivalent to a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change order of rows inside `<TABLE>` using javascript? Try this: http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/